# Creating dynamic function within a class for INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, function, class, mysqli

I was wondering if there is an good approach for creating functions within a class to make it easy to make insert/delete/update mysql queries.

For example

Let's say I have a table containing 12 rows, and I want to make an insert query with two values from within another class. How would the insert function look like? I would like this function to work with with any number of values.

```
function addUser($email, $password) {

    $values = array(
        "email" => $email,
        "password" => $password
    );

    $table = 'users';
    $query = $mysql->insert($values, $table);
}

function insert($values, $table) {
    // what would this look like? (note: this function is within another class.
}
```

I would eventually like to execute the query with prepared statements, something like:

```
if($stmt = $this->db->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->fetch()) {
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't do it. It's good idea, but better don't write own tool but also use already exist, for example doctrine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Mysql
{
    public static function insert($values, $table)
    {
        if(empty($values) || empty($table))
        {
            // Noting to do
            return "";
        }

        $list = array();

        foreach($values as $k => $v)
            $list[] = "`". $k ."` = '". $v ."'";

        $list = implode(",", $list);
        $query = "INSERT INTO `". $table ."` SET " . $list;
        return $query;
    }
}

$values = array
(
    "email" => "my email",
    "password" => "my password"
);

$table = 'users';
$query = Mysql::insert($values, $table);

echo $query;
```

There is no reason to use constructor here because all the data is static.
but if you wish so, just remove the `static` from the **insert** function
and initialize mysql like this:

```
$mysql = new Mysql();
$mysql->insert($values, $table);
```